# Pass output of a command as arguments to another(non-blocking)?

Tags: bash

I was wondering how I can iterate over each line of the output of a command and pass it as command line arguments to another one. I want to do this in a non-blocking fashion as the output never reaches an EOF.

To be more precise I want to take each line of output from `acpi_listen` and pass it to a user-level acpi handler script similarly to what acpid does as root(eg. "button/lid LID close" where $1="button/lid" $2=LID $3=close).

Comment: you mean like `tail -f acpi_listen | yourscript` (using a `readline` loop)?

Comment: yes kinda, but this way all the output seems to buffer until the program is terminated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possible, script below will launch `some_command` and passing every line in the file, and launch them in background, non-blocking:

```
cat input | while read param; do
    some_command $param &
done
```

Comment: Yeah this one doesn't wait for EOF though I had to pass param to xargs to split it into individual arguments. Thanks!